# Bootstrap does not always show popovers when generate dynamically

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am generating POPOVERS dynamically, it works great when you first time land on the page or first time it generates popovers, but as soon as you update the content and regenerate data for the popovers it stops working(popover won't show). Interestingly, when generate new content one more time it start to work again.

It seems like there is a pattern. It works for the first call, does not work for the second , but then work again for the third call and then stop working for the fourth call and so on.

Take a look at this [bootplay](http://www.bootply.com/pJ56zaLyj6). When run it first time you will see popover for all 6 boxes, click on the button on top left then it will stop working. Click on the same button again and it will work again.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: I initially can hover to see all 6.  After my first click, I only get 1,2,6.  Then after second click it toggles and I get 3,4,5.  Then it does just toggle them.   I am not familiar with the $.each function but I believe in your example, i is the element, not the elementid, so you'd want to change your comparison to `if(i.id == 'GA_timeonpage')`  You might want to remove a bunch of your javascript and confirm that popovers work well in your environment, then go add custom logic back in.

Comment: @RightClick code is iterating an object literal. That object has no `id` property

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. Although I am not 100% sure what was causing it.
I think there was not enough time between destroying the popover and rebuilding it again.

When I moved the

> $('.col-md-4').popover('destroy');

to click handler it works fine. Because then it destroy them and then call the function to build popover again.